# Как разместить два независимых друг от друга приложения на Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular2

Если добавить на страницу собранное приложение после тега `<app-one>`, с тегом `<app-two>`,  и добавить бандлы приложения 2, то при запуске вылетает ошибка

> Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.

Как добавить на одну страницу два разных приложения Angular4 чтобы они не конфликтовали?
Сильно ли это скажется на производительности?

Answer (score 2):

все, понял... поковырявшись в интеренатах понял, что это можно реализовать только при помощи сборщика SystemJS, вот линк, хотя люди тоже жалуются на похожую ошибку (https://blog.sstorie.com/bootstrapping-multiple-angular-2-applications-on-the-same-page/).

Если использовать angular-cli, то там добавлена только возможность отдельно создавать два приложения, но не запусктаь и билдить одновременно (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps).

Так что надо голосовать за эту фичу (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6428)

.angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [
{ "name":"app1",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main-one.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
},
{ "name":"app2",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist2",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main-two.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
}
],
```

структура:

```
src/
---/app1
---/app2
```

старт

```
ng serve --app app1
ng serve --app app2
```

Comment: Это одно приложение, а не два.

Comment: ты используешь ng-cli?

Comment: да, оба приложения используют Angular CLI

Comment: сейчас поправлю тогда ответ

Comment: Спасибо за старания, но кажется, ты не совсем понял вопрос. У меня есть страница, на которой уже есть приложение на 4 ангуляре. На эту же страницу необходимо добавить другое приложение, которое тоже на 4 ангуляре. Оба приложения уже собраны. Если в index.html инжектить второе приложение,они оба загружаются,но в консоле вылетает ошибка о том что zone.js уже загружен

Comment: так это и есть решение, у тебя по факту два приложения, которые будут отдельно билдиться, отдельно запускаться, но на одной странице без ошибок, попробуй

Comment: @ИюльАвгуст я дополнил ответ, хороший вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он приближенно похож, но не решает проблему) в моем случае нельзя пересобирать приложение в которое инжектим еще одно.Например: Есть приложение hello world( ng new hello-world), собираем его, и кладем в прод. Спустя месяц, надо разместить на странице к примеру проигрывватель, который тоже ng new player. Если тупо заинжектить бандлы второго приложения в первое, то появляются ошибки(приложение при этом работает), то нет гарантии что в процессе эксплуатации оно не рухнет. И возможно что первое приложение написано на 4, а следующее уже на 5+

Answer (score 0):

Два разных приложения предполагают два разных хоста, грубо говоря два разных сайта у каждого из которых свой адрес. Вам нужно на одной странице, тогда вы можете использовать модули, они специально для этого предназначены. Вы можете расшарить модули между несколькими приложениями.